# making a code into a function php

Tags: php, arrays, function

ok, so i had the following code (that worked exactly as i wanted on an array)
it works on an array called courseInfo()  and changes it.

```
$sizev1 = sizeof($courseInfo);
for ($row = 0; $row < $sizev1; $row++)
{
$tempsemhrs= $courseInfo[$row][3];
$tempday= $courseInfo[$row][4];
    if ($tempday == "א") $tempday=1;
    if ($tempday == "ב") $tempday=2;
    if ($tempday == "ג") $tempday=3;
    if ($tempday == "ד") $tempday=4;
    if ($tempday == "ה") $tempday=5;
    if ($tempday == "ו") $tempday=6;
$tempstarttime= $courseInfo[$row][5];
    if( (StrDelete($tempstarttime, 2, 3)-7) <10 )
        if( (StrDelete($tempstarttime, 0, 3)) == "45" )
            $tempstarttime= "0".(StrDelete($tempstarttime, 2, 3)-7+1);
        else
            $tempstarttime= "0".(StrDelete($tempstarttime, 2, 3)-7);
    if( (StrDelete($tempstarttime, 2, 3)-7) >=10 )
        if( (StrDelete($tempstarttime, 0, 3)) == "45" )
            $tempstarttime= (StrDelete($tempstarttime, 2, 3)-7+1);
        else
            $tempstarttime= (StrDelete($tempstarttime, 2, 3)-7);        


$courseInfo[$row][6]= ( $courseInfo[$row][2].$tempsemhrs.$tempday.$tempstarttime);
```

}

now, there is another few places i might have to use that code so i thought about making it into a function istead of doubling codes, but when i tried it didnt work anymore, all i did is copying it into function {} and changed the names inside and it doesnt work, im copying it down here also,  i'd love for someone to tell me where did i go wrong and why isnt it working now?

```
function addSortingCode ($tableChange)
{
$sizev1 = sizeof($tableChange);
for ($row = 0; $row < $sizev1; $row++)
    $tempsemhrs= $tableChange[$row][3];
    $tempday= $tableChange[$row][4];
        if ($tempday == "א") $tempday=1;
        if ($tempday == "ב") $tempday=2;
        if ($tempday == "ג") $tempday=3;
        if ($tempday == "ד") $tempday=4;
        if ($tempday == "ה") $tempday=5;
        if ($tempday == "ו") $tempday=6;
    $tempstarttime= $tableChange[$row][5];
        if( (StrDelete($tempstarttime, 2, 3)-7) <10 )
            if( (StrDelete($tempstarttime, 0, 3)) == "45" )
                $tempstarttime= "0".(StrDelete($tempstarttime, 2, 3)-7+1);
            else
                $tempstarttime= "0".(StrDelete($tempstarttime, 2, 3)-7);
        if( (StrDelete($tempstarttime, 2, 3)-7) >=10 )
            if( (StrDelete($tempstarttime, 0, 3)) == "45" )
                $tempstarttime= (StrDelete($tempstarttime, 2, 3)-7+1);
            else
                $tempstarttime= (StrDelete($tempstarttime, 2, 3)-7);        


    $tableChange[$row][6]= ( $tableChange[$row][2].$tempsemhrs.$tempday.$tempstarttime);
    }
 }
addSortingCode ($courseInfo);
```

Comment: http://php.net/functions - the topic is more broad, so it's normally suggested to read the manual about it and understand the concept before using. You're not that far of, but consider your function separate to the rest of the code and so are the variables there in. Important is: http://php.net/variables.scope

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `$tableChange` variable will not be modified inside a function. Try to pass-by-reference instead by change your function signature into

```
function addSortingCode (&$tableChange)
```

Comment: Yep. Without the `&`, `$tableChange` is a *copy* of `$courseInfo`, so modifying it is pointless unless you also return it and assign it to `$courseInfo`.

Answer (score 2):

you can do this:

```
//return the final contructed array(here $tableChange) as function output
function addSortingCode($tableChange)
{

     //your code
     return $tableChange;
}

//calling of the function

 $output = addSortingCode($courseInfo);
```

Comment: This and @Trung-Hieu Le's answer will both work.